# How can I make sure only ads relating to the "Travel and Locals" are shown in my app with AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I have an app that shows restaurants and I want my admob to only show ads relating to restaurants, hotels etc

How can I do this?

Comment: set an ad filter see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307260?hl=en&topic=1307248&

Comment: sorry http://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307260?hl=en&ref_topic=1307248

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you cannot set this kind of filter. From the AdMob help documentation:

> Can I filter or manage the keyword targeted and GCAN ads that run in my application? Do the existing filters I set for my application apply to these ads?
>
> No, at this time you are not able to apply any filters on the content of keyword-targeted or GCAN ads that run inside your application.

More information here: http://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307264?hl=en

Did that answer your question?